# JTAG connector for MINI8510

Tags: connector, cables, ribbon-cable

I recently bought an [SBC8100 plus board](http://uk.farnell.com/embest/sbc8100-plus-with-4-3-lcd/single-board-computer-dm3730-4/dp/2136526)

The board uses a [MINI8510](http://www.ti.com/devnet/docs/catalog/thirdpartydevtoolfolder.tsp?actionPerformed=productFolder&productId=9822) board. Now I want to connect to its jtag interface. On the image of the previous link it is the yellow connector, labeled as CN3 which is described as a "10-pin 1.0mm pitch connector".

[image: CN3]

The JTAG schematic:

[image: JTAG schematic]

The fact is that I'm fairly new to all this connector-cables stuff, and i can't figure out which kind of connector should i buy or where to buy it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the datasheet doesn't appear to be of much help. You could email the manufacturer for support to request information about the connector family used for the debug interface.

Comment: There are various 1mm pitch connector families - if you cannot get information from the board manufacturer, go to the website of a parts vendor and search what is available with the same pitch and contact count, and try to find something close.  It might fit well enough for occasional use.  You might also buy the mating connector for what you choose - if it doesn't fit, you can replace the connector on the board side. Or if you are impatient, get out that roll of multicolor wire wrap wire, solder to the pads and wrap the other ends on 0.1" header you glue somewhere secure.

Comment: But your link to the product says the package includes a "JTAG board"  - so why can't you use that?  It probably adapts to some semi-standard connector.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I did not received a jtag board. It was not listed on the package contents I received. I do not have the exact link of the one I purchased but it seems to me it was a cheaper package. Anyway, the board is the same. Also, on the manuals I received it is stated that the board can be connected to a XDS100v2, but I wonder how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally after some time looking for the original package I found the jtag board, as Chris commented.